# Displaying images using mySql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie coder.  This is a follow on question to the original one I posted.  I was having diffs displaying my images using php and mysql.  With the help of stackoverflow, my site now knows that I want to display an image, but when inspected using the developer tools on Chrome, it gives a 404 error and says the image cannot be found.

The image is stored as a png, but when I look at the 404 error I see that the browser thinks it is html/text.  I have tried swapping in other images that are displaying correctly elsewhere on my site, and they don't display either.

Why does chrome think my image is a html/text when the document has a .php extension, and my code says the image is .png?

Comment: Where is your project folder in which you are working? Means, In htdocs, have you created your project folder?

Comment: All my php docs are saved in htdocs and there is a folder in that called images, in which my images are saved.

Comment: Show me your Image submission form @Meabhy?

Comment: Hi Nana, I'm not using one. Is that just for Wordpress? I'm using Notepad++ and all the code is included in my question. Should I also be using an Image Submission Form?

Comment: If you are not using image submission form, then how it is inserting into database?

Comment: I am storing the path in the database, not the image. The attribute plant_img is type blob, and I used a mysql query to set the value to the file path of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don'T use the  tag in your second echo

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $row['plant_name'] . '</td><td><img src="' . $row['plant_img']. 
'"></td><td>' . $row['plant_type'] . '</td><td>' . $row['soil_ph_min'] . 
'</td><td>' . $row['soil_ph_max']     . '</td><td>' . $row['soil_type'].
'</td><td>' . $row['top_tip'] . '</td></tr>' ;
}
```

That should do the trick for you

Comment: I have amended it like you suggested Lucia. Now it does not show the file path, but it doesn't show the image either. The image is definitely named correctly and in the file.

Comment: you are running your site on a localhost so try not to use system specific imagelinks. 
Instead use project based links. for example
inside your htdocs directory, you got 2 projects.
Inside project a you got your current setup and an image directory
so your link would be 
localhost/project_a/images/beans.jpg
If you use chrome or Firefox to test your application, use the inspector (Browser tool) to check if everything is working.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the browser / inspector tool. Thank you! Some progress. It now displays that there should be an image, but it is not found. 

GET http://localhost/htdocs/images/beans.png 404 (Not Found)

I hadn't created a specific folder within htdocs as it will involve amending numerous other docs, but maybe that is the problem now. Should I have a project folder with all my docs within it, and a folder called images within it also?

Comment: there is no need for that, but never just copy paste stuff. that was just an example. tinker a bit around, how the url have to look like, you are close to the final solution!

Comment: Thanks for your help Lucia. I think you're right, I'm almost there.